# How to make all the contents in the android page scoll up

Tags: android

In my android application page I have use a slider, textview and a gridview to display images. Now the problem is that when I scroll up, only gridview images scrolls and rest of the things stays static. Please help me how can I make all contents of the page to move as I scroll?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >`enter code here`

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
          <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/one" />
         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/two" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/three" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/banner1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/banner2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/banner3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/banner4" />
    </ViewFlipper>    

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Shop For"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

      <GridView
          android:id="@+id/gridView1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:columnWidth="150dp"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
          android:numColumns="2"
          android:padding="28dp"
          android:stretchMode="none"
          android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
          android:visibility="visible" >
    </GridView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Place your all code in scroll view use following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/one" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/two" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/three" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/banner1" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/banner2" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/banner3" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/banner4" />

            </ViewFlipper>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Shop For"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:columnWidth="150dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:padding="28dp"
                android:stretchMode="none"
                android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

If you have any issue feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your layout xml file as like below, it would solve your issue, I guess.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/one" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/two" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/three" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/banner1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/banner2" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/banner3" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/banner4" />
        </ViewFlipper>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Shop For"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:columnWidth="150dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:padding="28dp"
            android:stretchMode="none"
            android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
            android:visibility="visible" >
        </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This could have happen as you are not using `ScrollView`. `ScrollView` should contain only one child view. So, use `LinearLayout` as a parent view for all other views and use this `LinearLayout` as child view to `ScrollView`.

Also `Gridview` acts as a `Scrollview` itself, hence in your case the `GridView` was scrolling but the other views were not scrolling.

Comment: thank u for the answer. i used the same code but its not working to scroll the entire page content...what more could be done..? please help me